# Velocity of point of intersection of 2 rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, velocity, faster-than-light

[image]

I'm not getting how are we getting u greater than c for part b by using formula for part a. Plz explain

Comment: It would be better if you could type your question rather than posting its photo. Photos are meant for diagrams and other things like that.

Comment: The text says "intersection of rods" but it's only one rod,  right? And according to the formula,  u is larger than v for angles less than 45 degrees.  At 60 degrees u is less than v, isn't?

Comment: The OP asks a specific question about a possible error in the book. It turns out that there is an error and by his question the error was identified. I don't think it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

As the inclined rod moves along $y$ at $v$ during $t$, the point of intersection appears to move along $x$ at $u$ during the same time. By applying simple trigonometry, we get: [See the attached Figure.]

$$u=v\cot\theta$$

However, it seems that there is a mistake in taking a proper value for $\theta$ or $v$ in Resnick's book according to which $u$ exceeds light speed. In the Persian translation of the book, the translator (Jafar Goodarzi) mentioned in the footnote of the relevant page that $\theta$, considering $v=c/3$, must be smaller than  ${18}°$. He thus chooses $\theta$ to be ${15}°$.

[image: Resnick exercise]

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: This is a correct explanation but OP was asking specifically about part b

Comment: @nasu Sorry, you're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Poo2uhaha Sorry, you're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, the values in the english version are wrong. What book is this?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @nasu It is the Persian translation of Resnick's *Introduction to Special Relativity* https://www.adinehbook.com/gp/product/9640101176

Comment: Thank you, Mohammad.